# How to find out which rows have changed values in a datatable

Tags: vb.net

I want to know if the rows have changed values in my Datatable, how to check that?
I got a Datatable has data and I make some changes on this data by grid view so Can I check which rows have changed.

Comment: You can store that data on an audit table

Comment: You can keep a hidden column (called something like `HasChanged` or `IsDirty`) and any time the user makes a change you can update that column to be `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `DataRow` has a [`RowState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowstate?view=netframework-4.8). When you populate a `DataTable` by calling `Fill` on a data adapter, all rows start out `Unchanged`. When you add a row the value will be `Added`, when you edit an existing row the value will be `Modified` and when you delete an existing row the value will be `Deleted`.

Note that, when you call `Fill` on a data adapter, the rows will be initially added with a `RowState` of `Added` but then `AcceptChanges` is called and they will all be set to `Unchanged`. If you set `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to `False` first, they will all remain `Added`. This is useful when, for instance, you want to retrieve from one database and then insert into another.

When you call `Update` on a data adapter to save changes, `AcceptChanges` is called afterwards and all `Added` and `Modified` rows become `Unchanged` and all `Deleted` rows are removed. If you set `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate` to `False` first, they will all remain as they were. This is useful when, for instance, you want to save changes to multiple tables from one `DataTable`. You would then call `AcceptChanges` manually if you wanted to keep using the `DataTable`.

Note that each `DataRow` contains two versions of its data: original and current. When you get data from a field in a `DataRow` you will get the current version by default, but you can specify which version you want. If the `RowState` is `Added` then the original version is empty and, if the the `RowState` is `Deleted` then the current version is empty. When `AcceptChanges` is called, the current version is copied over the original version in rows that were `Added` or `Modified`.

You can also call `GetChanges` on a `DataTable` and that will either return `Nothing` or a new `DataTable` containing just the changed rows. You can also specify one or more `DataRowState` values and get just changes of that type.

Comment: you are great man, thank you so much

Comment: Excellent answer!